# Removing elements from list in sml

Tags: function, duplicates, sml

I am a beginner in SML. I have found the following code which seems to work; however, I cannot understand how it works.

```
   fun delete(x,[]) = []
     | delete(x,y::l) = if x=y then delete(x,l) else y::delete(x,l);

   fun remove_dup [] = []
     | remove_dup (x::l) = x::remove_dup(delete(x,l));
```

This code removes duplicates in a list of any kind.

I have tried to replicate it using more basic syntax as

```
 fun remove (vec: int list)=
       if null vec
       then []
       else remove(hd vec::1) = hd vec::remove(delete2(tl vec, 1))
```

but I cannot do more.

Can someone please aid me?

Comment: There's nothing more "basic" about your syntax. You probably mean that it looks more  similar to other languages you've used. Once you get used to pattern matching, you're going to miss it in lesser languages.

Comment: It looks like you misspelled "l" ("ell") as "1" ("one").

Answer (score 2):

> ... the following code which seems to work; however, I cannot understand how it works.
>
> ```
> fun delete(x,[]) = []
>   | delete(x,y::l) = if x=y then delete(x,l) else y::delete(x,l);
>
> fun remove_dup [] = []
>   | remove_dup (x::l) = x::remove_dup(delete(x,l));
> ```
>
> I have tried to replicate it using more basic syntax ...

That seems like a sensible thing to do.

As molbdnilo points out in a comment, `hd` and `tl` are not more basic.

I might format `delete` like this:

```
fun delete (x, []) = []
  | delete (x, y :: rest) =
      if x = y
      then delete (x, rest)       (* delete y *)
      else y :: delete (x, rest)  (* keep y *)
```

One way to understand this function is to explain what it does:

- It takes one tuple of `(x, ...)` where `x` is a single element and the second part is a list of that kind of element. Pattern matching is used here, and so the list either takes shape of `[]` (the empty list) or `y :: rest` (the list with at least one element `y` and the remaining list of elements `rest`).
- When the list is empty (matches the pattern `[]`), the result is also empty: Deleting `x` from the empty list is done by simply returning the value `[]`. Notice that in `delete (x, []) = []`, the two `[]`s actually mean something slightly different: The first (on the left-hand side of `=`) is a pattern, and the second (on the right-hand side of `=`) is a value, an actual empty list.
- When the list is not empty, it means that it consists of at least one element, `y`, and a tail, `rest`. When there is at least one element, `y`, it means there is at least one candidate for deletion. If `x = y`, then the "deletion" consists of returning a list much like the input list, except with `y` not mentioned anywhere. So in the `then` branch, there is no mention of `y`, but instead only `delete (x, rest)` which means:

  The result is whatever is gained from deleting `x` from the rest of the list.

  Note also here that a similar distinction can be made about the pattern `y :: ys` and the value `y :: delete (x, rest)`. Here `::` is the value constructor for non-empty lists, and it is used to create a new list value where `y` persists. But the tail of that list may have copies of `x` deleted.

---

Another way to understand this function is by running it by hand.

Imagine a call like `delete (3, [1,3,3,7])`; I will make one rewrite per line, which corresponds to a reduction of the computation:

```
(*  1 *)   delete (3, [1,3,3,7])
(*  2 *) ~> if 3 = 1 then delete (3, [3,3,7]) else 1 :: delete (3, [3,3,7])
(*  3 *) ~> 1 :: delete (3, [3,3,7])
(*  4 *) ~> 1 :: (if 3 = 3 then delete (3, [3,7]) else 3 :: delete (3, [3,7]))
(*  5 *) ~> 1 :: delete (3, [3,7])
(*  6 *) ~> 1 :: (if 3 = 3 then delete (3, [7]) else 3 :: delete (3, [7]))
(*  7 *) ~> 1 :: delete (3, [7])
(*  8 *) ~> 1 :: (if 3 = 7 then delete (3, []) else 7 :: delete (3, []))
(*  9 *) ~> 1 :: 7 :: delete (3, [])
(* 10 *) ~> 1 :: 7 :: []
```

1. This is the initial function call.
2. Because the input list is non-empty, we skip the first pattern match and we fit the value `(3, [1,3,3,7])` onto the pattern `(x, y :: rest)`: You can do that easily by setting `x = 3`, `y = 1` and `rest = [3,3,7]`. After we do that, we replace `delete (3, [1,3,3,7])` with the full function body, `if ...` with the variables replaced.
3. Since `3 = 1` is false, the `else` branch is picked, so the entire expression is replaced with the sub-part in the `else` branch, `1 :: delete (3, [3,3,7])`.
4. Some interesting things happen here:

   1. Since `(* 3 *)` contains `1 :: delete (3, [3,3,7])`, you have two half-computed results: On the one hand you want to construct the list `1 :: ...`, and on the other hand, you don't know the tail `delete (3, [3,3,7])` yet, since it hasn't been computed.
   2. So before you can compute `1 :: ...`, you have to compute `delete (3, [3,3,7])`. This causes for a substitution of only the tail, so `1 :: (if 3 = 3 ...)`. Besides nesting the expressions, the reduction is pretty much the same, except...
5. Since `3 = 3` is true, the `then` branch is picked, and this results in only the value `delete (3, [3,7])` with no `y :: ...` part, since `y = 3` and we're deleting `3`s, doing `3 :: ...` would clearly be a wrong thing to do.

Things repeat this way (either including `y` or not) until `(* 9 *)` where `1 :: 7 :: delete (3, [])` is asking for `3` to be deleted from the empty list. For the first time, this triggers the first case of `delete (x, []) = []` and the recursion stops.

---

You can do a similar thing with `remove_dup`; running by hand, that is.

And you might find out that it isn't very trivial because it contains two recursive functions, one calling the other one and feeding its input directly. No matter how you twist and turn this function, it is going to be a little difficult.

There are some ways to make it look a little easier:

```
fun remove_dup [] = []
  | remove_dup (x :: rest) =
      let val rest_without_x = delete (x, rest)
      in x :: remove_dup(rest_without_x)
      end
```

and you may be able to at least spot that

1. `remove_dup [] = []`: Removing duplicates from the empty list is easy.
2. When there is at least one element, `x`, remove all occurrences of `x` from `rest` by doing `delete (x, rest)`. This list, which I called `rest_without_x`, is then fed to `remove_dup`.
3. Since we only remove *duplicates* of `x`, we want to include it once, and the one occurrence of `x` we pick is incidentally the first one we encounter.

If you want to run this by hand like in the example above, you probably want to run the original, compact one, though, since the function body only spans a single line. It could look like:

```
   remove_dup [1,1,1,2,2,3,1,2,3]
~> 1 :: remove_dup(delete(1, [1,1,2,2,3,1,2,3]))
~> 1 :: remove_dup([2,2,3,2,3])
~> 1 :: 2 :: remove_dup(delete(2, [2,3,2,3]))
~> ...
```

Notice that I resolve the inner expression `delete(1, ...)` before I can resolve `remove_dup(...)` since its argument was not yet resolved. (This is a consequence of strict evaluation semantics; some functional programming languages let you call a function without having fully evaluated its arguments!)

Try and complete the rest yourself.